# webview is forcing my scrollview to the bottom

Tags: android, android-webview, android-scrollview

I have a webview in a scrollview, when the Activity loads, it forces my scrollview to the bottom (where the webview is) once the webview finishes "loadData".
How do I keep this from happening?
I've tried this, but it jumps the screen up and down, which I don't want:

```
ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.detailsScroll);  
scroll.post(new Runnable()   
{  
    @Override  
    public void run()   
    {  
       ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.detailsScroll);  
       scroll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);  
    }  
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't put a webview in a scrollview. Scrollable views inside scrollable views doesn't work.

Comment: ok, so how should I do this if the contents of the Activity are larger than the screen?

Comment: ...and isn't this what admob is doing?  It seems like the webview is gaining focus once the contents are loaded, which is causing the scrollview to jump.

Comment: @steve: "how should I do this if the contents of the Activity are larger than the screen?" -- you can use a `ScrollView`, just keep the `WebView` outside of it. Allocate, say, 2/3rds of the screen to the `WebView` and the rest to the `ScrollView`, or something.

Comment: @CommonsWare - thanks, that makes sense.  I'm going to have to place this in a different Activity I guess, it's too large.

Comment: Isn't that a bit undesirable? What if I want the WebView on "bottom" of the ScrollView, so once a user scrolls completely the WebView can be seen, but only then?

Answer (score 10):

The answer of fhucho is OK for stoping the webview from scrolling to bottom. But you will lose all accessibility with trackball, etc. So I found an improvement :

```
public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {

    @Override 
    public void requestChildFocus(View child, View focused) { 
        if (focused instanceof WebView ) 
           return;
    super.requestChildFocus(child, focused);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Unfortunately that prevents the keyboard to show when clicking on input fields within the webview.

Answer (score 5):

Create a custom ScrollView with this method:

```
@Override
public void requestChildFocus(View child, View focused) {
    if (child instanceof WebView) return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For focus related issues, I found this worked better, adding these to your WebView in XML:

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Although for the actual question asked, just adding another view that gets the focus by default, instead of the WebView, should have resolved that issue.  I think others like me might find this when trying to deal with other general issues with a WebView inside a ScrollView taking the focus.  Adding the above to the XML does not stop hyperlinks in the WebView from working.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your main layout

**android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"**

Comment: This helps. But better add that to the parent of the `WebView` only.